# Blazor Server OnAfterRenderAsync not firing for components

Tags: asp.net-mvc, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I am trying to integrate blazor server into an existing MVC project, and am a little confused as to the requirements for getting my components to call `OnAfterRenderAsync()`.

I have the following simple `Index.razor` page for testing made up of the following:

```
@page "/Index"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        return base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

If I navigate directly to `/Index` the `OnAfterRenderAsync` method is hit just fine. But if I render `Index.razor` as a component in my `cshtml` like this:
`@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Index>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered ))`

Then the `OnAfterRenderAsync()` is not hit.

I have `MapBlazorHub()` in my `Startup.cs` and `<script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` in my `_Host.cshtml`.

Have I missed a step somewhere or is this behavior by design in Blazor Server, and if so, is there some workaround?
I need some reusable blazor components to be able to work with JS libraries that were implemented in the MVC project, so I need those components to be able to call `OnAfterRenderAsync()` without going directly to the page URL

Comment: And how did you establish that it is called? Because it is not.

Comment: I put a break point in the `OnAfterRenderAsync()` method and when I go directly to the URL `/Index` the breakpoint is hit. But when I render the component with `@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Index>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered ))` the breakpoint is not hit. But if I put a `OnInitializedAsync()` and break point in that, it is hit no matter how I render the component. I have no console errors but you are saying I must have another problem elsewhere? I just wanted to make sure this was not expected behaviour from Blazor Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After inspecting the sources in developer tools I saw that the folder for _framework was not present in my component.
Even though I could navigate to https://myurl/_framework/blazor.server.js and saw the file was present in my project, my component didn't have access to it. adding the script tag `<script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` directly to my cshtml file that was rendering my Blazor component fixed my issue.

Comment: Hello. I am facing the same issue as you described, but for some reason your solution did not work for me.
I am using ASP.NET MVC project (.NET 5) and want to implement server side blazor components in a razor page. When I navigate from the original component to the next in the same razor page, the OnInit method fires but the OnAfterRender does not. Can you give me some advices?